# Flutter - using same provider for updating dropdown and sending to data to another widget

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart, provider, state-management

I want to pass selected value from DropDown to its parent and then to child through constructor, after that update list by setState functions.

So, I want selected value from Dropdown be accessible in child of Restrictions (UserOffers).

Sending data from parent to child its actually working, but only when im passing data definied in parent class to child by constructor = im not sure if its a good way.

Now i am using provider to update data on Dropdown only, but i dont know how to pass it.

**CountryProvider class:**

```
class CountryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _items = [
    "Argentina",
    "Brazil",
    ...
   "Spain",
    "Switzerland",
  ];

  String _selectedItem;

  List<String> get items => _items;

  String get selected => _selectedItem;

  void setSelectedItem(String s) {
    _selectedItem = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**CountryDropDown class:**

```
class CountryDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountryDropDownState createState() => _CountryDropDownState();
}
class _CountryDropDownState extends State<CountryDropDown> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
...
          ChangeNotifierProvider<CountryProvider>(
            create: (context) => CountryProvider(),
            child: Container(
              width: 215,
              child: Consumer<CountryProvider>(
                builder: (_, provider, __) {
                  return DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text("Not selected"),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.flight),
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      provider.setSelectedItem(newValue);
                      dropdownValue = provider.selected;
                      print(newValue);
                    },
                    items: provider.items
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
...
```

And parent:

**Restrictions class:**

```
class Restrictions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RestrictionsState createState() => _RestrictionsState();
}

class _RestrictionsState extends State<Restrictions> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
...
Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: FieldDropDown(),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: CountryDropDown(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  child: DateSelector(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              child: UserOffers(
                country: selectedCountry,
                field: selectedField,
              ),
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Boras ! You made a lot of work for me with all the `...`.

I think you need to lift state higher up the widget tree so that `UserOffers` can change when the user selects a country from the drop down menu.

Complete example app below.

Note that I changed the model class name to `SingleSelectCountry`. An instance of that model class is not a provider. An instance of that model class is what is being provided by a provider. There's an important distinction there.

Note also that all the widgets extend `StatelessWidget`. Often with package provider you can avoid using `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// Model ---------------------------------------------------

class SingleSelectCountry with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _items = <String>[
    "Argentina",
    "Belgium",
    "Brazil",
    "Denmark",
    "England",
    "France",
    "Finland",
    "Germany",
    "Holland",
    "Ireland",
    "Norway",
    "Poland",
    "Scotland",
    "Spain",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Wales",
  ];

  String _selectedItem;

  UnmodifiableListView<String> get items {
    return UnmodifiableListView(this._items);
  }

  String get selected {
    return this._selectedItem;
  }

  set selected(final String item) {
    this._selectedItem = item;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}

// User Interface ------------------------------------------

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    // The provider has to be in the widget tree higher than
    // both `CountryDropDown` and `UserOffers`.
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<SingleSelectCountry>(
          create: (final BuildContext context) {
            return SingleSelectCountry();
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Home Page'),
        ),
        body: Restrictions(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Restrictions extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CountryDropDown(),
        UserOffers(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CountryDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SingleSelectCountry>(
      builder: (
        final BuildContext context,
        final SingleSelectCountry singleSelectCountry,
        final Widget child,
      ) {
        return DropdownButton<String>(
          hint: const Text("Not selected"),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.flight),
          value: singleSelectCountry.selected,
          onChanged: (final String newValue) {
            singleSelectCountry.selected = newValue;
          },
          items: singleSelectCountry.items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
            (final String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class UserOffers extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SingleSelectCountry>(
      builder: (
        final BuildContext context,
        final SingleSelectCountry singleSelectCountry,
        final Widget child,
      ) {
        return Text(singleSelectCountry.selected ?? '');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much!! But is it possible to use more consumers? I need actualy four - one more dropdown and two from datepicker.

Comment: It is possible to use more consumers. You can have four model classes `with ChangeNotifier` and then nest four `Consumer` or you can use `Consumer4`. Another option is to use a single model class `with ChangeNotifier` with four members and then `Consume` it in each place that needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now im struggling with implement it to DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, it works, but now im struggling with implement it to
> DatePicker.

no need to use consumer for widget with ShowDatePicker
just make callback with smth like Provider.of(context, listen: false).setDate1(DateTime.now())